# jquery code to get last string after<br>

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function testpassfail(jobid){
 var data;
    $.ajax({
   url: '/getJobReport?jobid=' + jobid,
    async: false,
  }).done(function (report) {
    if(report) {
      for(var browser in report) {        
        data = report[browser].result || '';
        data = data.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
        data = data.replace(/Passed/g, '<span class="pass">Passed</span>');
        data = data.replace(/Failed/g, '<span class="fail">Failed</span>');         
      }
    }    
  });
alert(data);//Checking button: Ok<br />Selecting ff: <span class="fail">Failed</span><br />Test <span class="fail">Failed</span><br />
return data;
}
```

my data data prints

```
data='Checking button: Ok<br />Selecting ff: <span class="fail">Failed</span><br />Test <span class="fail">Failed</span><br />'
```

from this how can i get the last data `Test <span class="fail">Failed</span><br />`

Comment: Your question is unclear to me

Comment: What part, specifically, are you trying to get?

Comment: How the response looks like?

Comment: Have you thought about building more dom around the data?  Clearly you're doing some data parsing and replacement in the `done` method.  Maybe you could just make you're report result parsing smarter so you could pull out the text you want by class or id (instead of looking for `<br/>` tags... just food for thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
var data='Checking button: Ok<br />Selecting ff: <span class="fail">Failed</span><br />Test <span class="fail">Failed</span><br />';
var array_fragment = data.split('<br />');
var result = array_fragment[array_fragment.length - 2];
```

This will return `Test <span class="fail">Failed</span>`

IF you want `Test <span class="fail">Failed</span><br />`, then perform concatenation with `<br />`

```
finalResult=result+'<br />';
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5nzPW/1/)

Comment: ok one more thing for outputing only `<span class="fail">Failed</span>` what changes i can made?

Comment: Use replace. `result = result.replace('Test ','');`